# jQuery ON KEYUP dynamically adds the second line of text fields but does not work on second line to add the third line

Tags: jquery, onkeyup

Hi all I am new to jQuery hopping I will get help here.

I have one line of 4 text fields. 
once the user starts typing in the 4th text field (last text field on the line)
I listen for jQuery KEYUP and generate the second line of 4 text fields. 
then 
once the user starts typing on second line of text fields and reaches the last text field (this is the place where I am stuck :) ) jQuery KEYUP must generate the third line which doesn't.

to try to troubleshoot my code i have put alert on keyup to see if the keyup event generated by the 4th text field get's me the correct PARENT which i would use to add my other line using AFTER()
and from alert i can see that i get the correct parent.

any suggestions?

here is the code I am using.

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var NewInvoiceLine = $('<div id="InvoiceLine"><div class="ItemFields" id="ItemQuantity"> <input id="Quantity" name="Quantity" type="text"></div><div class="ItemFields" id="ItemDescription"> <input id="Description" name="Description" type="text"></div><div class="ItemFields" id="ItemPrice"> <input id="Price" name="Price" type="text"></div><div id="ItemTotalPrice"><input id="TotalPrice" name="TotalPrice" type="text"></div></div>')

                $('#Invoice').on('keyup','#TotalPrice',function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    alert($(this).first().parent().parent().attr('id'));
                    $(this).first().parent().parent().after(NewInvoiceLine);
                    });
                });
</SCRIPT>
<style type="text/css">
.ItemFields{float:left;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form name="form1" method="get" action="">
<div id="Invoice">
<div id="InvoiceLine1">
  <div class="ItemFields" id="ItemQuantity"> <input id="Quantity" name="Quantity" type="text"></div>
  <div class="ItemFields" id="ItemDescription"> <input id="Description" name="Description" type="text"></div>
  <div class="ItemFields" id="ItemPrice"> <input id="Price" name="Price" type="text"></div>
  <div                    id="ItemTotalPrice"><input id="TotalPrice" name="TotalPrice" type="text"></div>
</div>

<div id="InvoiceButtons">
  <div id="Submit"><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
  <div id="Draft"><input name="Draft" type="submit" id="Draft" value="Draft"></div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi,welcome to the community.Can you provide more details and make your question more clear?

Comment: thanks OnlyMAJ. i have changed my text hope this is much clear.

Comment: The #TotalPrice selector will only register the keyup event for the first element it sees with id TotalPrice and not to the new ones you're generating. Assigning a class to the TotalPrice inputs and referencing it in the jquery selector for the keyup event might be a solution.

Comment: thanks for the comment Alain. I have tried that :) i have tried searching everywhere i am sure i am not the first one having this problem:) i have set the <input id="TotalPrice" to <input class="TotalPrice" and in my jQuery i used $('#Invoice').on('keyup',".TotalPrice" but still the same behavior as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this version is better and will also work server-side...

Also, you don't have to write the duplicating html in your code and therefore you can also update the html easily, cause It's reading the html dynamically (first line):

```
var InvoiceLine = $('#Invoice .InvoiceLine').eq(0).html();
$('#Invoice').on("keyup", ".ItemFields:last input", function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") $('#Invoice .InvoiceLine').last().after('<div class="InvoiceLine">'+InvoiceLine+"</div>");
});
```

A live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zys4p4rh/2/

Comment: But however please wait for my answer, cause IMO it's a bit better than Parody's...

Comment: yes this is cool :) actually this was my next step to find out how i can get the HTML of "InvoiceLine" and duplicate it again, instead of putting all HTML in my javascript then adding it to my page.

Comment: a things would be nice to know in your code. 1: why do you have [] in the names?

Comment: That's to get all inputs at submit. Othwerwise, I think, only the last inputs will count, cause name in the same form should be like id - unique. And with that [] it makes it as an array with all inputs...

Comment: Do you have some problems with it? What's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go i think this is what your after.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var NewInvoiceLine = '<div class="InvoiceLine"><div class="ItemFields" id="ItemQuantity"> <input id="Quantity" name="Quantity" type="text"></div><div class="ItemFields" id="ItemDescription"> <input id="Description" name="Description" type="text"></div><div class="ItemFields" id="ItemPrice"> <input id="Price" name="Price" type="text"></div><div class="ItemFields" id="ItemTotalPrice"><input id="TotalPrice" name="TotalPrice" type="text"></div></div>';

    $('form').on('keyup','.ItemFields:last-child',function(){
        var a = $(this).parents(".InvoiceLine").next(".InvoiceLine");
        if(a.length > 0){
            return false;
        }else{   
            $(this).closest(".InvoiceLine").after(NewInvoiceLine);
        }

    });
});
```

By changing the `div` with the `id` of InvoiceLine to a `div` with the `class` InvoiceLine you don't have the issue of having multiple elements with the same `id`.

Then your able to use the it like i have in the function above to get the desired effect i think your after.

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z7ox4qpx/) showing it in action

Comment: yes this is what i am looking after :). Do i always have to use class ? having several same IDs in html causes a problem i guess?

Comment: Yes `id`s should be unique, if you wish to have multiple elements that use the same css or to be used in a function like above use classes instead and np.